# How to Delete Rows with SQLite.SWIFT?

Tags: swift, sqlite, sqlite.swift

I use [SQLite.SWIFT](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift) and want to delete rows with specific id from my table.

The documentation [here](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#deleting-rows) said that I can use:

```
let delete = delete.update(email <- "alice@me.com")
if let changes = delete.changes where changes > 0 {
    println("deleted alice")
} else if delete.statement.failed {
    println("delete failed: \(delete.statement.reason)")
}
```

I could not find a global `delete` function. My table is

```
let users = db["users"]
```

**How do I perform the delete.update function?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would appear to be a typo in the documentation. You can do something like so:

```
let alice = users.filter(email == "alice@mac.com")
let delete = alice.delete()
if let changes = delete.changes where changes > 0 {
    println("removed \(changes) record(s) for Alice")
} else if delete.statement.failed {
    println("delete failed: \(delete.statement.reason)")
}
```

Comment: FYI, I've posted issue [#179](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/issues/179), so we'll see what the author has to say.